# Why does Today or Now equal a negative value?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Why does an assignment of A Datetime Object to Today or Now equal a negative value? Or why does this code produce a negative value as the output?

```
                Public Class Form1
                    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                        Dim timevar As Date
                        timevar = Now
                        Console.WriteLine(timevar.ToBinary)
                    End Sub
                End Class
```

Output is:
-8586339480225014672

Comment: You change the encoding base of your value from decimal to binary then from binary to decimal without considering their rules. So "negative" has no meaning anymore. In example the binary value 101 may mean 5 if you're in a 3 bits unsigned system (values allowed are then 0 to 7) and -1 in a 3 bits signed system (values allowed are then -3 to 3)

Comment: It is because interpreting the bits in the wrong way can give a meaningless result.

Comment: Because the documentation says so: "A 64-bit **signed** integer"

Comment: The two most significant bits in the private Long variable that stores the date are used to implement the Kind property.  When DateTime.Kind is DateTimeKind.Local, always the case when you use Now, then the most significant bit is set and that makes the binary value negative.  Compare to UtcNow, won't be negative.  Pure implementation detail that is not supposed to matter, ToBinary() is only useful to easily serialize a DateTime.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thank you. If you guys must know, I was trying to do modulo division on the Longs so I could see if my TimeSpan was a multiple of an hour. I used .Ticks to convert and then used Mod to divide. Worked out pretty good. Any alternate solutions?

Answer (score -1):

I would use `DateAndTime`

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim timevar As Date = DateAndTime.Now
        Console.WriteLine(timevar.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Check this link out by [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime?view=netframework-4.8)